# Linking to previous/next PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink

I am creating a PHP/MySQL site which has records giving details about images.

Each record contains the field image_id (the key) and image_name.

I want to create a link on each page to go to the next record based on image_name rather than ship_id.

I have the current image_id and image_name as parameters in the URL. I've got as far as this line for the link but it just links to the current page... any help????

```
<a href="<?php printf("%s?pageNum_ship_image_info=%d%s", $currentPage, max(0, $pageNum_ship_image_info - 1), $queryString_ship_image_info); ?>">Previous</a>
```

Comment: Using `$currentPage` as the first parameter to `printf` suggests that the URL you're generating links to the `current page`.

Comment: thanks Mike, I'm really just using guess work on dreamweaver to try and achieve this... do you have any bright ideas or know where I can look? I'm really at a loss. thank you

Comment: How you do things like this depends entirely on your application and page structure. Assuming that linking back to the current page with a different query string is the right thing to do, you need to make sure that the query string you are generating matches the format expected by the page. I have no idea what that is. From what you've posted here it's impossible to say very much more.

Comment: OK thanks, I'm sure you don't want to see all the code so I shall struggle on... thanks x